Zipping and download files failed. Returning symbols in the terminals
my download zip code not working. The zip contains of some xls files
I got error when attempting to generate export file.
I'm using PHP.
The code is like this:
$directory = Yii::getAlias('@console/runtime/tmp');
if (!file_exists($directory)) {
   mkdir($directory);
}

$this->zip = new \ZipArchive();
$this->zipFile = tempnam($directory, "zip");

....
$html = '<table><thead><tr><th>no</th><th>name</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
$output = '';
$output .= "<html>\n";
$output .= "<head>\n";
$output .= "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />\n";
$output .= "</head>\n";
$output .= "<body>\n";
$output .= $html;
$output .= "</body>\n";
$output .= "</html>\n";

$fileName = "test" . '.xls';

if ($this->zip->open($this->zipFile, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
   file_put_contents($fileName, $output);
   $this->zip->addFile($fileName, basename($fileName));
}

$this->zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $this->getFilename());
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($this->zipFile));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($this->zipFile);
exit();

The result 
what should I do to make it work? I already spent 3 days on this problem

Not clear. Are you executing the script through CLI?

I'm using queue to download the file

I don't understand what that means. With that code, you are supposed to use a browser to download the file.

@SusyValentinaRahardjo Try to add to this line of code an file extension $this->zip->addFile($fileName, basename($fileName) . '.txt'); as an example
